# Convert unicode to emoji

Tags: swift, emoji

I'm looking for a way to represent an emoji  in my code as unicode which is then displayed as an actual 'image' in output text. I'd like to use http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F4C4 to display the 'page facing up' in application, but I don't like the idea of having pictures in my code (though it is working fine) ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use arbitrary Unicode characters directly in your source code

```
let string = ""
```

or use the Swift Unicode escape sequence:

```
let string = "\u{1F4C4}"
```

More information in the section about ["String Literals"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) in the Swift reference.

Comment: Yes I did use the emoji itself in my code, but as I said, I don't like the idea of having images in it. Swift escape sequence is working great so thanks for answer!